React Helmet Async - CSR
Lately we have had issues with meta tags in google indexing. They were working before but don't seem to be any more.
Does anyone have an explanation on why this is the case? Thank you in advance.

We have double checked the tags and they are correct
In Google search console when looking at indexed sites - the meta tags from React helmet are not there
However if we try "Test Live url" - we can see that the tags are there

I know that the code is correct, I was wondering if there would be any other explanation to why this would be happening

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Are you working with Gatsby? My Gatsby site is experience the same issue. We are using Gatby's Head API (which uses React Helmet under the hood, I think) for SEO. I am thinking of manually implementing React Helmet to fix the issue.
